# airflow receiving data from cloud function via trigger

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am currently following this example of using Cloud Function to trigger a DAG on Composer

https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/triggering-with-gcf

It is shown that you can send additional data through the argument data of trigger_dag_gcf. But I am quite unsure how can I use those passed data in the DAG itself

Answer (score 1):

To Deploy a Cloud Function that triggers the DAG.

For example: The function `def trigger_dag_gcf` which is the part of the [code](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/triggering-with-gcf#deploy_a_cloud_function_that_triggers_the_dag) which triggers the DAG, where you pass the id of the Dag.

```
def trigger_dag_gcf(data, context=None):
     
      web_server_url = (
          "https://example-airflow-ui-url-dot-us-central1.composer.googleusercontent.com"
      )
      # Replace with the ID of the DAG that you want to run.
      dag_id = 'composer_sample_trigger_response_dag'
```

The DAG that prints the result:

```
import datetime

import airflow
from airflow.operators import bash_operator
default_args = {
    'owner': 'Composer Example',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'email': [''],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': datetime.timedelta(minutes=5),
    'start_date': datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1),
}

with airflow.DAG(
        'composer_sample_trigger_response_dag',
        default_args=default_args,
        # Not scheduled, trigger only
        schedule_interval=None) as dag:

    # Print the dag_run's configuration, which includes information about the
    # Cloud Storage object change.
    print_gcs_info = bash_operator.BashOperator(
        task_id='print_gcs_info', bash_command='echo {{ dag_run.conf }}')
```

For more information you can refer to these links [Trigger dag with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59683095/trigger-dag-with-parameters)
and [How to execute Cloud Composer DAG with some runtime parameters from Cloud Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59960198/how-to-execute-cloud-composer-dag-with-some-runtime-parameters-from-cloud-functi).